# QWidget reports incorrect size

Tags: python, pyside

I have a program, where i am trying to center a window on screen.
The window appears to be the size of my layout, which is somewhere around 200px wide, but QWidget.size() reports a width of 640px.

[image: In the image is the actual window]

My code is basically setting a QVBoxLayout to a QWindow, and then setting it visible with show().
Is the layout supposed to automatically report size to widget? Is there a way to get the size of the layout?

I've tried activating the layout, getting widget size as rect(), with no results

Heres the minimal example:

```
python
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class windowClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, layout):
        super(windowClass, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(layout)

class layoutContainer:
    def getLayout():
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("This is a minimal example"))
        return layout

app = QApplication([])
        
layout = layoutContainer.getLayout()

window = windowClass(layout)

print(window.size()) # output: PySide2.QtCore.QSize(640, 480) 
window.show()



sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Layouts don't have sizes.

Comment: @mahkitah i figured, since it wasn't mensioned in the docs

Comment: Your code is not setting anything: `getLayout()` returns `None`, so you're practically doing `self.setLayout(None)`. You should at least add `return layout` at the end of `getLayout`. Note that while PySide accepts doing that, PyQt will crash, as `None` is not an acceptable argument type.

Comment: All widgets have a default size until actually mapped: widget created without parents always have a default size of 640x480, and that will stay the same until the layout is finally activated (which happens after the first call to `sizeHint()` of the widget); then Qt will eventually try to adapt the window based on that given size and finally resize the inner layouts accordingly.

Comment: @musicamante Right, i forgot it in my haste, and now the example works, im gonna delete the post and do a deep dive

Comment: @musicamante thank you for the answer, it steered me in the exact direction, while the answer luckily wasn't as stupid as not returning a layout, turns out the window size only gets set after the window itself is set visible

Comment: @Brosbud `return layout` is in the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR FUTURE REFERENCE**

I've pinpointed the problem, and above code reflects it.
The show() method sets window size FROM default to reflect layout.
And thus, size() should only be called after the window is visible

Additionally should be noted, as @musicamante very clearly explained, if the widget positioning needs to be in any way accurate, `sizeHint()`
should be utilized

Comment: That's inaccurate, even if a layout is eventually set, there is absolutely no guarantee that what you get from `window.size()` at that point in code will actually reflect the final size the window will have when displayed, which may depend on many factors (including OS and window manager, or the fact that the widget itself is added to another layout). The only thing you can reliably do is to get the `sizeHint()` of the widget *once the layout is set*, and eventually change its geometry based on that. This may still be changed by the OS afterwards, anyway.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for the clear and concise explanation